# SELECT distinct for multiple rows of same ID

Tags: distinct, rows

I have a view result that looks like below

```
B_ID | CL_ID | TPROVIDER | STMT_ENBLD | Source_ID
1    | ABCD  |    T1     |     Y      |    1
2    | ABCD  |    T1     |     Y      |    2
3    | ASDF  |    T2     |     N      |    1
4    | QWEI  |    T1     |     Y      |    1
5    | ZXXC  |    T1     |     Y      |    1
6    | ZXXC  |    T1     |     Y      |    2
```

I want a query which would give result like

```
B_ID | CL_ID | TPROVIDER | STMT_ENBLD | Source_ID
2    | ABCD  |    T1     |     Y      |    2
3    | ASDF  |    T2     |     N      |    1
4    | QWEI  |    T1     |     Y      |    1
6    | ZXXC  |    T1     |     Y      |    2
```

when there are multiple records with same CL_ID, it should check If TPROVIDER = 'T1' and STMT_ENBLD ='Y' and if so,it should fetch only one record from that two, where Source_ID=2

Answer (score 0):

I think GROUP BY CL_ID would do the trick to get the records together.

Comment: group by cl_id will give the error Column 'B_ID' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.